Simulating Quantization Noise based on Allan Noise Coefficient
I have an observation sequence from an accelerometer from which I have computed an Allan deviation curve and derived the noise coefficients of the various noise contributions. Based on these parameters I am trying to generate/simulate an observation sequence that would result in the same Allan deviation curve. I managed to do this by simulating random noise for the velocity random walk, a first order Gauss-Markov process for the bias instability and using a polynomial for adding systematic variation.
However, I have trouble figuring out how to simulate the quantization noise.
From the Allan deviation curve I have derived a quantization noise coefficient of 12.35 micro-g/Hz.
How do I use this information to add quantization noise to my simulated observation sequence?


An ideal memoryless uniform scalar quantizer can be modeled as an additive noise as shown below 
where the quantization noise $\epsilon$ is a uniform random sequence $\epsilon_{n} \sim U[-\Delta/2,\Delta/2]$ with variance $\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2} = \frac{\Delta^{2}}{12}$. Now that you obtain the quantization noise coefficient from Allan deviation plot, you have obtained the standard deviation $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ of the quantization noise.
Thus, if you have the quantized sequence $Q(x_n)$ (denoted by qx vector in the code snippet below) you just need to add a uniformly-distributed random noise to that sequence, for example, in MATLAB, you can do
Delta = sqrt(12)*sigma_epsilon;
epsilon = (Delta/2-(-Delta/2))*rand(size(qx))+(-Delta/2);
y = qx + epsilon;

If you want to introduce the quantization noise to the input sequence $x_n$ you can do the following in MATLAB
fs = 1000;         % Sampling frequency (Hz)
t = 0:1/fs:10;     % Time vector (10 seconds)
x = sin(2*pi*1*t); % Example sine wave
Delta = 0.01;      % Quantization step size
xq = round(x/Delta)*Delta;

Note that there are further details that you may want to consider to simulate a practical quantization that happens in an ADC, e.g., number of bits (word length, fraction length), rounding method, and overflow methods. What I put in the code above is just for the sake of simulation. If your observation sequence $x_n\in[-1,1]$, then the number of bits $N$ is given by $\frac{2}{\Delta} = 2^{N} \Rightarrow N = \lceil 1-\log_2(\Delta)\rceil$. The number of bits can also be obtained from SQNR rule of thumb $SQNR = 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{\sigma_{x}^{2}}{\sigma_{\epsilon}^{2}}\right) = 6.02N + 1.7~\text{(dB)}$.
Hope this helps.

Thank you for your response! I am really stuck here, so any help is appreciated!
If think there is only one point in your answer that is not clear to me - regarding the relation between quantization noise coefficient and standard deviation. Do you mean this is simply (in case of 100 Hz sampling rate)?:
sigma = 12.35 micro-g / Hz * 100 Hz

Additionally, I followed your instructions by rounding with the derived delta value as you describe and adding the uniformly distributed noise. I would then expect that the slope of the first part of the derived Allan deviation curve would be -1, corresponding to quantization noise. However, this does not seem to have any influence on the slope of the curve. Am I expecting something wrong?
